# executing functions by object type, instead of using if else if else

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java application that receives a Json encoded object when when i decode it back to an object I need to execute a relevant function appropriate to the relevant object.

I have like 50 objects and per each object I need to execute a function and to deliver to that function this object. which means that I have 50 `if else` statements in my code.

I use google-gson to decode the json string back to the object.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Packet packet =  (Packet) gson.fromJson(msg, cls);
```

and then I have

```
   if (packet instanceof FooVO) {
            func1(packet);
   } else if (packet instanceof BarVO) {
            func2(packet); 
   }
   ...
```

and so on...

now i'm not that expert in java so I'm wondering is there a way to shorten these if/else statements and to somehow create a class that it's functions are based on the object type and to call a function based on the returned type of the object ?

any method that would save me using if else so many times in my code!

thanks!

Comment: packet is an abstract class that all other classes inherits from it

Comment: oops yeah it's packet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you'd be able to have all fifty objects' classes implement a common `RunAfterDeserialize` interface with a `runAfterDeserialize` method, so that you can cast the object to a `RunAfterDeserialize` and execute its `runAfterDeserialize` method.

Barring that, create an abstract `RunAfterDeserialize` class and create fifty subclasses with their own `runAfterDeserialize` method implementations, corresponding to the fifty different object types you've got (e.g. `FooVORunAfterDeserialize`, `BarVORunAfterDeserialize`).  Now create a `Map<Class, RunAfterDeserialize>`, where you get the key via `object.getClass()` for your fifty objects.  Then you can execute the appropriate method with

```
Map<Class, RunAfterDeserialize> map;
Packet packet =  (Packet) gson.fromJson(msg, cls);
map.get(packet.getClass()).runAfterDeserialize(packet);
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest would be to have all your possible classes implement the same interface and in it define an `abstract` method. After reading the object from `Json` you just need to call `packet.func();` and leave the implementation details to the different classes themselves.

As mentioned in your comment, you already have this common base class and can therefore define the `abstract` method in your `Packet` class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can have an Interface with that method `method()` and all your other classes implementing the method of that Interface.  Then once you get an object from the JSON , you can call that method as `packet.method()`.  Each implementing class will override the method in its own way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your processing code decoupled from the various `Packet` implementations, the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is what you're looking for.